# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies inject point

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, cdi

I have a working Dynamic Web Project (JAX-RS) in eclipse which fetches records from database and return data in json format.

Now, i am trying to split this project into two.

```
1. CompDB  //Project stores database handlers classes

src
  database
    ComponentContext.java
    ComponentViewable.java //Interface
  database.uat
    ComponentUATView.java  //Implements ComponentViewable
  META-INF
    persistance.xml
WebContent
    WEB-INF
      beans.xml
       web.xml
```

Created a jar file and copied onto WEB-INF/lib of project 2 as below

```
2. CompRS //Project stores JAX-RS client classes
src
  compreport
    ComponentData.java
  META-INF
    persistance.xml
WebContent
    WEB-INF
             lib
                CompDB.jar
     beans.xml
             web.xml
```

When I run CompRS on glssfish 3.1, getting below error

```
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [CompRS] at [/CompRS] SEVERE: Exception while loading the app

INFO: file:/C:/Program Files/glassfish-3.1.2.2/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/CompRS/WEB-       INF/lib/CompDB.jar_ci logout successful

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type 
[ComponentViewable] with qualifiers [@ComponentContext] at injection point [[field] @Inject @ComponentContext compreport.ComponentData.componentdata]
```

Here is the code

ComponentData.java

```
@Path("component")
@RequestScoped
public class ComponentData {
@Inject @ComponentContext ComponentViewable  componentdata;
@GET
@Path("latest")
@Produces("application/json")
    ....
}
```

ComponentContext.java

```
@Target({TYPE,METHOD,PARAMETER,FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME) @Documented @Qualifier
public @interface ComponentContext{}
```

I am very new to create multiple jars and integrate them. If this is not the correct way to do, please guide me to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like CompDB is now a jar that you're referencing from the other web app. The beans.xml files in a jar must be in META-INF.